# Install apk programmatically with DocumentFile

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, documentfile

This is how i install a apk file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now i want to install a apk file from sdcard, i'm getting the uri through Storage Access Framework (From Kitkat), but code does not working.

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.fromFile(file); //file class File
Uri uri2 = df.getUri(); //df class DocumentFile
```

The code with uri1 works, but not with uri2

Any workaround?
Thanks

Comment: The last time I checked, the package installer will only accept `file://` `Uri` values. Since there is no requirement that the `Uri` you get from the Storage Access Framework actually be a file, you would need to copy the data to your own file (`getContentResolver().openInputStream()` plus Java I/O). That file would need to be on external storage, so both you and the package installer can access it. Then, use a `Uri` pointing to that file. With luck, they improved the package installer in 6.0 to support other schemes, but I doubt it.

Comment: @CommonsWare i'll do that. Thanks a lot.